sorting on nested property with prisma
i'm using prisma and typescript, and i want to sort role in a table, but when i sort the role, the console will put error like this
`Argument user_roles: Got invalid value 'asc' on prisma.findManymme_user. Provided String, expected mme_user_roleOrderByRelationAggregateInput:
type mme_user_roleOrderByRelationAggregateInput {
_count?: SortOrder
}
here's my code
export async function getUser({ skip, limit, pageSize, search, sortBy }: { skip: number, limit: number, pageSize: number, search: string, sortBy: { id: string, desc: boolean }[] }): Promise<any> {
    const sorting: { [key: string]: string }[] = sortBy.length > 0 ? sortBy.map((sort: any) => {
        if (sort.id.includes('.')){
            const idArr = sort.id.split('.')
            let nestedSort: any = { [idArr[idArr.length-1]]: sort.desc ? 'desc' : 'asc' }
            idArr.reverse().forEach((id: string, index: number) => {
                if(index > 0){
                    nestedSort = { [id]: nestedSort }
                }
            })
            return nestedSort
        }
        return { [sort.id]: sort.desc ? 'desc' : 'asc' }
    }) : [{ userid: 'asc' }]

    console.log('sorting', JSON.stringify(sorting, null, 2));
    console.log('sortby', JSON.stringify(sortBy, null, 2));

    const filter = [
        {
            userid: {
                contains: search
            },
        },
        {
            nama: {
                contains: search
            },
        },
        {
            role: {
                contains: search
            },
        },
        {
            email: {
                contains: search
            },
        },
    ]

    return prisma.mme_user.findMany({
        skip,
        take: Number(pageSize) < Number(limit) ? Number(pageSize) : Number(limit),
        include: {
          user_roles: {
              include: {
                  role: true
              }
          }
        },
        
        where: {
            is_deleted: 0,
            OR: filter
        },
        orderBy: sorting
    })
}

my prisma schema looks like this
model mme_role {
  id         Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String          @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  privileges mme_privilege[]
  user_roles mme_user_role[]
}

model mme_user_role {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  user_id Int
  user    mme_user @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  role_id Int
  role    mme_role @relation(fields: [role_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
}

model mme_user {
  id                 Int                      @id @default(autoincrement())
  userid             String                   @unique(map: "idxUser") @db.VarChar(25)
  passwd             String                   @db.VarChar(250)
  nama               String                   @db.VarChar(50)
  role               String                   @db.VarChar(15)
  email              String                   @db.VarChar(250)
  created_at         DateTime                 @db.DateTime(0)
  last_updated       DateTime                 @db.DateTime(0)
  is_deleted         Int                      @default(0) @db.UnsignedTinyInt
  deleted_at         DateTime?                @db.DateTime(0)
  logged_in          Int                      @default(0) @db.UnsignedTinyInt
  activities         mme_activity[]
  notifications      mme_notification[]
  product_price_list mme_product_price_list[]
  user_roles         mme_user_role[]

  @@index([is_deleted], map: "mme_user_is_deleted")
}

i already try _count to sort the data, but i want to sort it alphabetically
